# Há algum dicionário antes da reforma ortográfica de 1911?

Tags: ortografia, recursos

Em 1911, houve uma reforma ortográfica que fez a ortografia portuguesa menos etimológica:

> "**escripto**" para "escrito";
>
> "**theatro**" para "teatro";
>
> "**pharmacia**" para "farmacia"
>
> "**abysmo**" para "abismo"
>
> "**diphthongo**" para "ditongo"; etc.

É visível a não alteração noutras línguas, como em inglês:

> "**script**";
>
> "**theatre**";
>
> "**diphthong**".

Eu tentei procurar um dicionário que contivesse palavras antes da idem reforma, porém, não encontrei nenhum.

Existe um dicionário antes dessa reforma ou há outro lugar melhor para saber-se como se escrevia?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Existe um dicionário antes dessa reforma?*

Sim, por exemplo:

- **1806:** [*Novo diccionario da lingua portugueza, composto sobre os que até o presente se tem dado ao prelo, e accrescentado de varios vocabulos extrahidos dos classicos antigos, e dos modernos de melhor nota, que se achaõ universalmente recebidos*](https://archive.org/details/novodiccionario00unkngoog/page/n6/mode/2up)

> [image]

- **1813:** [*Diccionario da lingua portugueza recopilado dos vocabularios impressos até agora, e nesta segunda edição novamente emendado, e muito accrescentado*](https://archive.org/details/diccionariodalin02mora/page/n3/mode/2up) por Antonio de Moraes Silva.

> [image]

Você pode encontrar mais resultados no [archive](https://archive.org/search.php?query=title%3A%28diccionario%20portugueza%29%20AND%20mediatype%3A%28texts%29) pesquisando, por exemplo, por *diccionario portugueza*  e restringindo a data até 1911.

Comment: Obrigádo pela resposta!